# catching multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

```
public class OfficeTimeXception {
    public int inTime;
    public int outTime;

    public void anyXception() throws CoreHourXception, NormalHourException {
        int k = outTime - inTime;

        if (inTime > 11) {
            throw new CoreHourXception(inTime - 11);
        }
        if (k < 8) {
            throw new NormalHourException(8 + (inTime - outTime));
        } else if (outTime < 16) {
            throw new CoreHourXception(16 - outTime);
        }
    }
if my try & catch statement is 


    {test.inTime = 12;
        test.outTime = 19;
        try {
            test.anyXception();
        }

        catch (CoreHourXception e) {
            System.out.println("core hour exception by" + e.getTime()
                    + " hours");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NormalHourException e) {
            System.out.println("normal hour exception by" + e.getTime()
                    + " hours");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

I need to catch both exceptions when both conditions fail....but Iam able to get only coreHourException even when both the conditions failed.

Comment: What is the relationship between `CoreHourXception` and `NormalHourException` ?

Comment: are you mentioning multi catch block?

Comment: It's not possible for a method to throw two or more exception types - when some exceptional situation happens, then an `Exception` that corresponds to it is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge `CoreHourXception` and `NormalHourException` into an `HoreException` which reports which conditions are violated:

```
public class HourException extends Exception {
    private boolean normalViolated_;
    private boolean coreViolated_;

    public HourException(String message, boolean normalViolated, boolean coreViolated) {
         super(message);
         normalViolated_ = normalViolated;
         coreViolated_ = coreViolated;
    }

    public boolean isCoreViolated() {
         return coreViolated_;
    }

    public boolean isNormalViolated() {
         return normalViolated_;
    }
}
```

This is similar to Stephen C's solution. But instead of storing multiple message strings (which cannot be evaluated easily by any exception handler), you explicitly store the information about the violated constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can only throw one Exception at a time, and code execution immediately stops when you do that (the later validations are not run at all).

If you want to check for multiple errors and return all the results at once, you have to collect the validation errors in a Collection and return that Collection (for example by attaching it to a wrapper Exception).

For example

```
List<Exception> errors = new List<>();
if (errorConditionOne) errors.add(new CoreHourXception());
if (errorConditionTwo) errors.add(new SomeOtherException(123, "abc"));
if (!errors.isEmpty) throw new ValidationException(errors);
```

These objects that you put in the errors Collection do not have to be Exception objects themselves, they can be anything that you find convenient to convey the information.

Comment: This is an solution which is well suited for situations where a **wide** range of exceptions can occur. In the example the two Exceptions are very similar and one could decide to better merge them in a single exception class (as done in Stephen C and my answer), with the advantage of fewer classes and more concentrated information. But in the end this is a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to catch both exceptions when both conditions fail....

That is impossible in Java ... and every other programming language I've ever come across.

Basically, only one exception can be thrown and can propagate at a time, and therefore only one exception can be caught.

If you want your code to report all of the failures, then you need to do something like this:

1. Create an empty list of messages.
2. Check each condition, one at a time.  If the condition "fails", then add an error message to the list.
3. When you have checked all of the conditions, see if the list is non-empty.  If it is, then EITHER convert the list of messages to a string and throw an exception with that string as the message OR throw an exception with a list field, passing the list to the exception via a constructor argument.

You can then catch the exception, and deal with the (possibly) multiple error conditions it is reporting.

Cumbersome?  Yes!